# Read XML from DB, convert it to json in php

Tags: php, json, xml, simplexml

I have some XML in my database (several entries, each containing a  elem as root).

When i read it from database whats the best way to convert it to json? I need to pass it to a js function. Currently my attempt looks like that:

```
    <?php 
    $utf8 = utf8_encode($ADM_CONTROLLER->getForm($id)->getPages());
    $utf8 = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $utf8);
    $utf8 = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $utf8));
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($utf8);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var form = '<?=$json?>';
        loadForm(form);
    </script>
```

Problems:
1. it can't convert to simpleXML, giving me an "there is extra content at the end of the document" warning, when it clearly was valid xml.
2. It seems my replacement stuff, doesn't work. I still have quite a lot of spaces between different tags and since i use utf8_encode() quite a lot of /t, /r, /n.

Thanks for any good ideas.

Comment: Please stick to one question at a time. The error you are encountering has nothing to do with converting to JSON (which is a horrible idea - just extract the information you need), and whitespace is not affected by `utf8_encode` (which should really be called `iso8859_1_to_utf8`). You'll also need to give us an example of the XML that's failing to parse, ideally [one we can test](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or there's nothing we can do but make wild guesses, which is a waste of your time and ours.

Comment: your XML is *not* valid. XML to be valid it must be *well-formed* first. If it would have been *well-formed* then you wouldn't see `simplexml_load_string` emit the error. So the XML is not *well-formed* and therefore it could not be *valid*. Remove as much code as possible that processes the string before loading it and try to read it as early as possible as XML. If that still fails, the source of the XML string provides invalid XML. If not, the code you introduced created invalid XML. In that later case, load it as XML first and then do the whitespace normalization.

Comment: You should provide the string data returned by `$ADM_CONTROLLER->getForm($id)->getPages()` in your question instead of having the function call there. Otherwise your example is not reproduceable and not good answers can be given (as it is not clear what you're actually asking about in concrete).